# How to put pre-existing text in an ordered list?

Tags: html, emmet

I have some pre-existing recipe ingredients that I want to put into an order list in the HTML file. Like the list below, is there a way to put each ingredient into the list without manually copy and pasting it one by one? I am currently trying to use emmet abbreviations and so far I tried `ol>li*13> ["paste in the ingredients"]` it does not work.

e.g.

Sticky Garlic Shrimp

```
salt
pepper
sesame seeds
lemon slices
cooked brown rice (to serve)
1 tablespoon reduced-sodium soy sauce
1 teaspoon fresh ginger, minced
1 tablespoon olive oil
1 spring onion
1/4 teaspoon crushed chili flakes (optional)
3 cloves of garlic, minced
3 tablespoons honey
1400g uncooked shrimp, peeled & deveined
```

and I want it in the following:

1. salt
2. pepper
3. sesame seeds
4. etc

Comment: Here's a little list creator I built based on my answer below: https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/PoRxqKG. You can paste in your list like you have in the question and it will output your list items wrapped in `<li></li>` elements for you to copy and paste. Enjoy!

Comment: This is very useful, I will try to implement this in my project going forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste your text lines into editor first, select them and then wrap with abbreviation with `*` marker: https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it accomplishes the original goal of using Emmet. +1

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, doing this with JS is the way to go, but if you don't want to convert your list to an array first, let JS handle that and you can use `split()` to create the array for you.

```js
// Set a varaible to your multiline list and use the backticks to create a string literal.
let ing = `salt
pepper
sesame seeds
lemon slices
cooked brown rice (to serve)
1 tablespoon reduced-sodium soy sauce
1 teaspoon fresh ginger, minced
1 tablespoon olive oil
1 spring onion
1/4 teaspoon crushed chili flakes (optional)
3 cloves of garlic, minced
3 tablespoons honey
1400g uncooked shrimp, peeled & deveined`;

// now get your array using the '\n' new line selector to create each value.
let ing_array = ing.split('\n');
// the parent div
let ing_parent = document.getElementById('ingredients');

// now loop through each element in the array.
ing_array.forEach( elem => {
  // create an li element
  let li_elem = document.createElement('li');
  // add the text from the array to the li
  li_elem.append(elem);
  // append the li element to the ul.
  ing_parent.append(li_elem);
});
```

```html
<ul id="ingredients">
</ul>
```